# CSS @import not working for local file - File path is correct

Tags: css, import

In my site I've tried these two methods (One for each time), to import a font:

```
@import "/va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf";

@import url('/va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf');
```

None of them is working. The path is correct.
I don't want to use a HTTP request for this task.

PS: Tried without the quotes too: `@import url(/va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be missing a back-slash in there, I believe the correct syntax is `@import url(//address);`, I'm not sure though if it would work with a local file.
I personally would define a font-face in my CSS and use that as a regular font-family property. Always worked for me that way whether for local files or fonts online.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('/va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

For the record, I learned the code above some time ago from [CSStricks.com](https://css-tricks.com)

I hope that answers your question.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I only need it to use the ttf font.

Comment: `format` is a property of the `src` modifier, is simply explains to the browser how the file in the `url` is formatted, there is a list of standard formats that browsers are expecting from the CSS code. In this case, it's the format of that specific font file.

Comment: In case you were wondering, the font you linked in your code above `FjallaOne-Regular.ttf` is a `truetype` format.

Comment: If you are only importing a `truetype` font, then skip all the other lines. I've edited my answer to reflect that. Keep in mind that you might run into some compatibility issues if you use older IE browsers as they don't support `truetype` fonts (I think all versions prior to 9)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you are using an import, not the `@font-face`, try the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FjallaOne-Regular'; /*You can use whatever name that you want*/
    src: url('/va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Finally, select the font-family on your sections, for example:

```
#styledDiv {
    font-family: 'FjallaOne-Regular';
}
```

Good luck, bro.

Comment: path not working, worked when I moved the file to the same path as the css, then removed the folder path. Should I use a `.` before the backslash?

Comment: You can use `..` to go back one directory. For example:

`src: url('../va/fonts/FjallaOne-Regular.ttf');`